# I have worked in/at/within (the) x industry for a while

Tags: prepositions

I would like to ask which preposition should be used with the word industry in an example as follows.

> I have worked at/ in / within  the tourism industry for a while.

Is *the* necessary or does it add extra meaning to the sentence?

Comment: I don't know the correct answer, but it's definitely not "at".

Comment: You have worked in an industry and you should use "the" because there are many different types of industry. You could say: "I have worked in tourism".

Comment: When people say “the industry” and don’t specify which, they often mean the industry of pornography production, just by the way.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worked%20in%20the%20industry%2C%20worked%20within%20the%20industry%2C%20worked%20at%20the%20industry&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworked%20in%20the%20industry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworked%20within%20the%20industry%3B%2Cc0), *in* is far more common in print than *within*, and *at* doesn't register as used at all:

[image: in the industry versus within the industry versus at the industry]

---

*Industry* is both a countable noun and a mass noun, but *tourism* is only a mass noun and cannot be counted.

As such, the following breaks down what's grammatical and what's ungrammatical:

> ✔ I worked in the tourism industry.
>   ✔ I worked in a tourism industry.
>   ✔ I worked in the industry.
>   ✔ I worked in an industry.
>   ✔ I worked in industry.
>   ✔ I worked in tourism.
>
> ✘ I worked in the tourism.
>   ✘ I worked in a tourism.
>   ✘ I worked in tourism industry.

Note that the error of last sentence doesn't logically follow from the syntactic use of *industry* as a mass noun and *tourism* as an attributive noun; however, it's simply not idiomatic.

Also note that the grammatical sentences don't all have the same meaning.

---

If you're talking about the tourism industry in general, which would be more normal than not, using **the** is the most common way of expressing that.

In short, the following is the most common phrase:

> I worked ***in the*** tourism industry for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you can belong to X, *in X* is a shortcut for saying "belonging to X".

X in *work at X" must be a place, not a group.  Destinations such as times, measurements, or goals are also useable with *at X*.

So you might work *at* a factory while you are *in* a training group.  Since a factory is something that surrounds you on all sides, you can work *in* one too, but you can't be *at* the training group unless you're trying to say you're in the same place as the other members of the group (and even then it's a bit awkward).